# How can I make link_to in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want the link which goes to

`http://example.com/shop/:shop_name`

so it should be something like this.

```
<%= link_to "Shop", req.host + "/shop/"+ @shop.shop_name , :class => 'btn' %>
```

I don't want to use `something_path` or `something_url` here.

I just want to create url link from **current host**, and **variable**.
How can I?

UPDATE:

```
  <%= link_to "Shop", request.host + /shop/ +@shop.shop_name , :class => 'btn' %>
```

This takes me to

`http://www.example.com/shop/www.example.com/shop/walmart`

Comment: do you need the "http://example.com" prefix, else what you have should work.

Comment: What is the link your code example provides? And how is it not correct? I do not see what we are asked to help you with...

Comment: @Vegar I added more info to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with,

```
<%= link_to "Shop", "/shop/"+ @shop.shop_name , :class => 'btn' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use url helpers? Doing it by hand is error-prone.

Simply put this to `routes.rb`

```
get "shop/:name", to: "shops#show", as: "shop_name"
```

Then you can use this in your templates:

```
<%= link_to "Shop", shop_name_path(@shop.shop_name), :class => 'btn' %>
```

In the `show` action of `shops` controller just fetch the `name` param:

```
shop_name = params[:name]
```